# how to insert records using django models then run a update query

Tags: django, django-models

Hi I have the following model,

```
class members(models.Model):
  auto_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  member_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, default='')
  father_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, default='')
  wife_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, default='')
  HID = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

I am using Django-rest Serializers to insert records.

In above HID is a number given to each member but it may change depending upon the insertion.

Eg:
1,2,3...10  HID numbers are given for 10 members
Now a new member is child of 3 then his number would be 4 and 4 should become 5 until end it should update
Now if a member 4 is deleted then 5 should become 4 and 6 should become 5 like that it show happen

How can I implement this concept with Django models and views?

Note: I know the number after which the insertion should happen I can choose that person or HID

Comment: I think you should use https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt

Comment: If you have an absolute super model, initiate a list there. The list contains all unique identification of any super and sub instances. So if you create a superinstance, you can `insert` that instance's unique identification at an specific index (that can be handled by a method). And in turn deleting an instance simply pops the list-entry with that identification. This way, the list-indexes of each instance would represent your HID numbers.